# Question about creating a volume form for $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

This problem comes out of R.W.R. Darling (Differential Forms and Connections) ch.8. In the chapter he shows that if $M$ is an $n$-dimensional differential manifold immersed in $\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$, and $\Psi$ is an immersion from $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ that parametrizes the manifold, and $f$ is a submersion from $\mathbb{R}^{n+k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^k$ such that $f^{-1}(0) = M$, then we can construct a volume form $(\star df)$ on $M$ using the Hodge star, and that $(\star df)\Lambda^n \Psi_{*}$, which parametrizes the volume form, is given for $k=1$, and $\Psi(0) = r$ by 
$$ \begin{vmatrix} D_1 f(r) & D_1 \Psi_1(0) & \cdots & D_n \Psi_1(0) \\
                         \vdots & \vdots      & \ddots & \vdots      \\
                         D_n f(r) & D_1 \Psi_n(0) & \cdots & D_n \Psi_n(0) \\
\end{vmatrix}. $$
The exercise is to do this with the submanifold $SL(2,\mathbb{R}) \subset GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ regarded as equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^{nxn}$, with $\Psi$ parametrizing $\begin{pmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \\ \end{pmatrix}$ as the image of $(x,y,z)$ and $f(x,y,z,w) = xw - yz - 1.$ I calculated this, and got: 
$$ \begin{vmatrix} w & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
                  -z & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
                  -y & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
                   x & \frac{-w}{x} & \frac{z}{x} & \frac{y}{x} \\
\end{vmatrix}, $$
where $w = \frac{1+yz}{x}$, which correctly evaluates at $I$ to give $-2dx\land dy\land dz$ as the parametrized volume operator.

The second part is where I have a problem, it says to extend this volume form in a left-invariant manner to $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ by calculating $(L_A^{*}(\star df))(A^{-1})$, where $L_A$ is the left shift operator on $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$, with $L_A \begin{pmatrix} s & t \\ u & v \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x & y\\ z & w\\ \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} s & t \\ u & v \\ \end{pmatrix}$ when $A = \begin{pmatrix} x & y\\ z & w\\ \end{pmatrix}.$

I sense that I should take $(L_A^{*}(\star df)) = ((\star df)L_{A{*}})$ to start the process, but am confused as to how the push-forward fits into the calculation with respect to the parametrization $\Psi$.  Could someone help me with how that works? And do I calculate $L_{A{*}}$ as an element of $\mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ which gives a differential as a 4x4 matrix? And if so, does it pre-multiply or post multiply which of the various pieces of the matrix determinant needed to form the volume form? (The problem is 8.4.5 in Darling, p.173, and this is a self-study question.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would suggest that you practice computing some pullbacks in a more basic setting. For example, if $f(u,v)=(u+v^2,uv,u^3+v^3)=(x,y,z)$ what is $f^*(x\,dy\wedge dz + z\,dx\wedge dy)$? You should learn how to do this without ever writing down a push-forward.

Second, you want to compute $L_{A^{-1}}^*(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz)(I)$. Since $A^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}w&-y\\-z&x\end{bmatrix}$, we have 
$$\begin{bmatrix} w&-y\\-z&x\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} dx &dy\\ dz &dw \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} wdx-ydz&wdy-ydw\\-zdx+xdz&\dots\end{bmatrix},$$
so $dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ pulls back to

\begin{align*}
(wdx-ydz)\wedge (wdy-ydw)\wedge (-zdx+xdz)&=-dx\wedge dz\wedge (w dy-ydw)\\ &=-dx\wedge dz\wedge (w-yz/x)dy \\&=\frac 1x dx\wedge dy\wedge dz.\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, very much.  Here is my problem:  I can answer the first problem you posed, I've worked many of them trying to understand this one.  I am very grateful for your explaining how to do the pullback of the left-shift of the inverse, I wasn't understanding that. But I do not see how it is interpreted as being evaluated at the identity. If it were evaluated at, say, B, how would that change what you wrote?  I can calculate the argument, *df and then substitute as you did from matrix multiplication, and that gives me what? The pullback of left-shift by $A$ of *df at the identity?

Comment: Remember that we're trying to use left-invariance to deduce what the volume form will be at an arbitrary point $A$ given that we know what it is at the identity. I'm frankly not exactly sure what your question is now. Also, be careful writing $^*df$, as that means something totally different.

Comment: The problem was to evaluate $L_{A}^{*}(\star df)(A^{-1})$ to do that. If I follow your advice, then doing $\star df$ carefully and evaluating at $I$, I get everything I'm supposed to get, and the way you describe it sounds like just what I'm trying to get, and my understanding of it. But then I don't understand why the author's expression is evaluated at $A^{-1}$ and yours was at $I$. Yours makes sense, his seems like he wants it translated back or something?  Sorry to be so dense about it, but I've breezed by these things for years and am mystified that it was so hard to do out in detail.

Comment: First of all, I'm sorry I had forgotten the context of your question and didn't pay attention to the $\star df$ in the original setting. I used to own Darling's book, but gave it away when I retired a few months ago. I think the problem is screwy. The first part asks you for the volume form at $I$, so presumably we want to use that to compute the volume form at an arbitrary point $A$. Note that I'm telling you to take the pullback of the volume form at the identity, whereas he's telling you to pull back $\star df$ by $L_A$ and evaluate the result at $A^{-1}$. These are different notions.

Comment: I prefer my approach, but his will work. Note that $L_A^*\omega(A^{-1})(v_1,\dots, v_3) = \omega(L_A(A^{-1}))(L_{A*}v_1,\dots,L_{A*}v_3)$. This approach, to my mind, involves more computation, but you can do it.